# Stroke at coordinates on HTML canvas with Javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, html5-canvas

I'm attempting to stroke a svg path on a particular location of a canvas, but I'm not sure how I can indicate the coordinates of where to stroke the path. How can I do that? I have the following code so far.

```
var path = new Path2D(//path string here);
ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
ctx.stroke(path);
ctx.fill(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some searching answered this for me: [How to position Path2D SVG element in canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59631446/how-to-position-path2d-svg-element-in-canvas)

Courtesy of Blindman67, I can translate the position as follows.

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let p = new Path2D('M10 10 h 80 v 80 h -80 Z');
ctx.translate(100, 100);
ctx.fill(p);
```